# Getting a value from another model Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-model

How do I get a value and make it appear on a dropDownlist on yii2

For example I have 2 models which is hotel guest and service request.
I wanna get the hotelguest_id value from its model and store it on a dropdown on the service request.

Similar like this.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'hotelguest_id')>dropDownList(yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(hotelguest_id::find(->all(), 
'id', 'id')) ?>
```

Comment: Instead of hotelguest_id put model name, like HotelGuest

Comment: I'm trying to create a dependent dropdown that gets the hotelguest_id. I already figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

I already figured it out

By using

```
use app\models\Hotelguest;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

<?= $form->field($model, 'hotelguest_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Hotelguest::find()->all(), 
 'id', 'id'), ['prompt' => 'Select Hotel Guest ID']); ?>
```